# Scrapy Error Handling for 404,403,301,302

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from a list of urls. And for the urls which are not giving response status code 200 I do need some other data.

**settings.py**

```
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [404,403,301,302]
```

**Code**

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = ScrapedataItem()
    
    if response.status != 404 or response.status != 403 or response.status != 301 or response.status != 302:
        item["url"] = response.url
        item["status"] = response.status
        item["html_data"] = response.text
    else:
        item["url"] = response.url
        item["status"] = response.status
        item["html_data"] = "Site Error"
```

**Log**

```
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 231,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 12,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 38,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 4,
```

Here  `else` part is not executing. I want to make the else portion to execute if error codes come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this is

No need to set in settings.py

We can handle error by adding list of error codes `handle_httpstatus_list` to spider file

```
class CrawldataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'crawldata'
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404,403,301,302]


def parse(self, response):
    item = ScrapedataItem()
    if response.status in (404,) or response.status in (403,) or response.status in (301,) or response.status in (302,):
        item["url"] = response.url
        item["status"] = response.status
        item["html_data"] = "Site Error"
    else:
        item["url"] = response.url
        item["status"] = response.status
        item["html_data"] = response.text
```

Comment: You could just write `if response.status in self.handle_httpstatus_list:`